# Converting imported dataset columns to DateObject

Tags: dataset, date-and-time

I'm really banging my head against a wall here with something that feels like it should be simple. I am importing a .csv with a header row as a Dataset. One of the columns is Time, formatted as YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS.SSS. I want to be able to plot the data as a time series. I am able to interpret a single entry as a time easily with

`DateObject[dataset[1, "Time"]]`

but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a column with this series. I'll spare you the details of all the things I've tried...

```
dataset = Dataset[
  {<|"Time" -> "20211105 10:54:00.996", "x" -> 14.81`, "y" -> 14.683`,
     "z" -> 0.1`, "i" -> 0.8`|>,
   <|"Time" -> "20211105 10:54:01.188", "x" -> 14.809`, 
    "y" -> 14.659`, "z" -> 0.1`, "i" -> 0.8`|>,
   <|"Time" -> "20211105 10:54:01.380", "x" -> 14.784`, 
    "y" -> 14.649`, "z" -> 0.1`, "i" -> 0.8`|>,
   <|"Time" -> "20211105 10:54:01.572", "x" -> 14.768`, 
    "y" -> 14.646`, "z" -> 0.1`, "i" -> 0.8`|>,
   <|"Time" -> "20211105 10:54:01.796", "x" -> 14.809`, 
    "y" -> 14.643`, "z" -> 0.1`, "i" -> 0.8`|>}
  ]
```

TIA

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It would help if you included a sample of your data in a form that can be copied and pasted. e.g. `dataset[1 ;; 5] // Normal`. To add a new column named `DateTime` to your dataset with the string values converted to `DateObject`: `dataset[All, <|#, "DateTime" -> DateObject[#Time]|> &]`

Comment: Thanks @RohitNamjoshi,
On the right track. This line works perfectly with the 5 lines of example data I added to my original post. However, when I try it with my real data (20k rows) I get ```Failure: String Time cannot be interpreted as date.``` I restarted my kernel and don't have any variables ```Time``` or anything like that. Only thing I am doing differently as far as I can tell is using ```Import``` (with option ```Dataset```) to bring in the data.

Comment: See `Query` and `ApplyTo` to get `dataset //= Query[All, {"Time" -> DateObject}]`

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like the `Time` column for some row(s) contains the text "Time" rather than a date/time. Try `dataset[Select[#Time == "Time" &]]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi yep, down on line 558 there was another set of headers. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks for your help!